# How to Call DAO from a SQL query string in C#

Tags: c#, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I know that in springboot you can call DAO directly from sql string.

I.E

```
SqlQuery = "
  SELECT new com.testProject.model.testDAO(test.country, test.code, sum(case when test.dummy1  = 'POS' then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when test.dummy2 = 'POS' then 1 else 0 end))
  FROM test";
```

But is Possible to Call a DAO from Sql string in C#? I Removed the DAO from the query to make it work:

```
SqlQuery = "
  SELECT test.country, test.code, sum(test.dummy1 = 'POS' ? 1 : 0) as dumm1, sum(test.dummy2 = 'POS' ? 1 : 0) as dummy2
  FROM test";
```

Is there any way to call DAO inside SQL query string?

Comment: _"Is there any way to call DAO inside SQL query string?"_ X-Y. Do it the "C#" way. When writing in .NET/C#, don't _think_ in Java/Spring.

Comment: if you use the entity framework, you can do something like that:
`var myResult = await yourDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<YourClassHere>("Select ...").ToListAsync();` and it will map the result of the query to your class

Comment: I'm uzing azure functions with http and CosmosDB trigger, and passing SQL query string in cosmos db trigger function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you are using azure http trigger with cosmos db input,there is no such `DAO` mechanism like spring boot with query string param in cosmos db input per my knowledge.

However,based on the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-sqlquery) provided on the Azure Function Cosmos Db Input document,it supports using custom Object Class to map the query result from sql. Please refer to my test:

Sample data in cosmos db :

[image]

Azure Function Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CosmosTriggerCore
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "db",
                collectionName: "coll",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosdbstring",
                SqlQuery = "SELECT top 2 * FROM c")]
                IEnumerable<TestDoc> testDocItems,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            foreach (TestDoc doc in testDocItems)
            {
                log.LogInformation(doc.Id);
                log.LogInformation(doc.Name);
            }
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }

    public class TestDoc
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I used `TestDoc` Class to accept the query result and i can access the properties in the code.

[image]